# 405 Error with cURL FTP

Tags: c++, curl, ftp

I'm trying to FTP up a file via cURL and am receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed. I've followed the example from [the documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html), but no luck so far. The only additions to the example are the `curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "*******:*******" )` and the ftp address. I've spent most of my time figuring out the correct ftp URL format is and the current error is a result of what I believe is right.

NOTE: When using `#define REMOTE_URL "ftp://*********.com/home/*********/public_html/data/"`, cURL returns `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

/* <DESC>
 * Performs an FTP upload and renames the file just after a successful
 * transfer.
 * </DESC>
 */

#define LOCAL_FILE      "data.csv"
#define UPLOAD_FILE_AS  "ftpd.csv"
#define REMOTE_URL      "http://*********.com/home/*********/public_html/data/"
#define RENAME_FILE_TO  "renamed-and-fine.txt"

/* NOTE: if you want this example to work on Windows with libcurl as a
 DLL, you MUST also provide a read callback with CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.
 Failing to do so will give you a crash since a DLL may not use the
 variable's memory when passed in to it from an app like this. */
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    curl_off_t nread;
    /* in real-world cases, this would probably get this data differently
     as this fread() stuff is exactly what the library already would do
     by default internally */
    size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*) stream);

    nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

    fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
            " bytes from file\n", nread);
    return retcode;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *hd_src;
    struct stat file_info;
    curl_off_t fsize;

    struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
    static const char buf_1 [] = "RNFR " UPLOAD_FILE_AS;
    static const char buf_2 [] = "RNTO " RENAME_FILE_TO;

    /* get the file size of the local file */
    if(stat(LOCAL_FILE, &file_info)) {
        printf("Couldnt open '%s': %s\n", LOCAL_FILE, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

    printf("Local file size: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes.\n", fsize);

    /* get a FILE * of the same file */
    hd_src = fopen(LOCAL_FILE, "rb");

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        /* build a list of commands to pass to libcurl */
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_1);
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_2);

        /* we want to use our own read function */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

        /* enable uploading */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

        /* specify target */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL);

        /* username and password */
        curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "*******:*******" );

        /* pass in that last of FTP commands to run after the transfer */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, headerlist);

        /* now specify which file to upload */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

        /* Set the size of the file to upload (optional).  If you give a *_LARGE
         option you MUST make sure that the type of the passed-in argument is a
         curl_off_t. If you use CURLOPT_INFILESIZE (without _LARGE) you must
         make sure that to pass in a type 'long' argument. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                         (curl_off_t)fsize);

        /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* clean up the FTP commands list */ 
        curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */ 

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `REMOTE_URL` starts with `http://`. Thus, curl connects to http server at 80 port and tries to send it non-http commands. FTP is different service at different port (21) and requires `ftp://` schema for curl to properly connect.

Comment: I thought that too, but it keeps giving me a `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Comment: That's strange. Can you download from ftp server with curl from [command line](http://superuser.com/a/265066/418234)? What OS are you using? Have you built libcurl yourself from sources?